# Failed to execute 'send': Websockets.

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, glassfish

Наше приложение написано на Java 8, использует application-server glassfish 4.1.1. Часть функционала реализована с использованием технологии WebSockets.

На серверной стороне Websocket-ы реализованы через @ServerEndpoint (Если необходимо, могу привести код). Порт явно не указан. Погуглив, выяснилось, что в этом случае они используют дефолтный порт 80 (поправьте, если я всё-таки ошибаюсь).

В целом веб-приложение работает хорошо, пользователи не испытывают проблем с подключением к нему и к вебсокетам.

Однако на одной из машин веб-приложение не загружается с ошибкой:

> failed to execute 'send' on websocket: Still in CONNECTING state

На машине того пользователя используется Google Chrome, поэтому нет оснований думать, что вебсокеты там могут не поддерживаться.

В чем может быть проблема? Почему она проявляется в такой странной форме только на одном компьютере (может быть еще у кого-то, только мне об этом неизвестно)?

Есть какие-либо идеи? Будем очень благодарны!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле проблема крылась в proxy той сети, в которой находился компьютер того пользователя. Оказалось, что т.к. мы используем незащищенный протокол (ws), прокси-сервер подправляет заголовки запроса и тем самым портит его (запрос).

Достаточно очевидным решением в этой ситуации явился переход от незащищенного (http) к защищенному (https) протоколу. И, соответственно от ws к wss, если говорим про вебсокеты.

Т.к. передача через защищенный протокол осуществляется в зашифрованном виде, прокси-сервер более не имеет возможности "подправлять" заголовки и "пропускает" запрос как есть. В конечном счете соединение успешно устанавливается.

В целом же большое спасибо всем, кто проявил участие и помог мне разобраться с этой проблемой!

Answer (score 1):

Метод send необходимо вызывать только когда ws.readyState === 1, обычно это наступает после события onopen.

```
ws.onopen = function(){
   ws.send({param1:'test'})
}
```

Comment: Да, до этого уже дошли своими силами. Однако проблема не ушла. Соединение просто не проходит теперь. Грубо говоря, readyState не становится == 1. Вероятно виноваты настройки браузера/антивируса/системы. Есть ли какие-то идеи?

Comment: Проблема очевидно в браузере. На сколько помню у WebSocket есть несколько протоколов, возможно сервер не поддерживает именно тот протокол, который реализован в этом браузере. Версия старая? На деле с таким сталкивался только один раз, и это было одной из старых версий Safari.